# How to add XML attributes to request in SOAP?

Tags: php, xml, soap

I need to create SOAP request like this:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:stor="http://storage.xdoc.xx/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <stor:createDocument>
         <parentEntryId>workspace://SpacesStore/15f33e3a-32ba-4a5d-976f-c9e2096e1112</parentEntryId>
         <name>test.txt</name>
         <properties module="" name="Content" type="Binary">
            <valueBinary>
               <bytes>cXdlcnR5</bytes>
            </valueBinary>
         </properties>
      </stor:createDocument>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

As far as I understand I need to use nested arrays, but the problem is in the XML properties. SoapVar seems to be not exactly what I need.

Now I have such a call:

```
$client->__callSoap("createDocument",
                                array(new SoapParam($name, "name"),
                                        new SoapParam(
                                                new SoapParam(
                                                        new SoapParam(
                                                                $contents,
                                                                "bytes"
                                                        ),
                                                        "valueBinary"
                                                ),
                                                "properties"
                                        )
                                )
                        );
```

How to add attributes to "properties"?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've tried some variants to make this work - with nested arrays, and stdClass, and SoapVar enconded arrays, and combinations, etc. But the only variant I found to be working properly is that:

```
 $parameters = new stdClass();
 $parameters->name = $name;
 $parameters->parentEntryId = $parentEntryId;
 $parameters->properties = new stdClass();
 $propsSimpleVar = new SoapVar("<properties module=\"\" name=\"Content\" type=\"Binary\"><valueBinary><bytes>" . $cleanContents . "</bytes></valueBinary></properties>", XSD_ANYXML);

 $parameters->properties = $propsSimpleVar;

 $client->createDocument( $parameters );
```

I think it should work with array for properties too.
Hope this'll be useful for someone else.